# how to get key -> value order?

Tags: laravel

I have this code:

```
Setting::where('section', $section)->select('key', 'value')->pluck('value')->toArray();
```

it produces this:

```
  0 => "true"
  1 => "native"
  2 => "true"
  3 => "true"
```

I need this

```
 enable => "true"
 type => "native"
 must_be_registered => "true"
 allow_nested => "true"
```

how do I get that? I tried pluck('key', 'value') but that did not return all values from DB for some reason some were missing, this is what came out:

```
 array:3 [▼
      "true" => "allow_nested"
      "native" => "type"
 ]
```

it came out in value => key order and was missing keys and values

How can I get key => value?

Comment: use select as statement like: key as val and value as key. this might work

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong after you test it but, if you select key and value, you return those two. If you "pluck" value out of it, you're actually loosing the 'key'. does it work if you just remove the pluck part?

Comment: it does not work if I remove the pluck part, then a different array is produces, where each key and value are inside an array of its own

Comment: Pluck is for getting all column values. use like Setting::where('section',$section)->select('value as k','key as v')->get();

Comment: great thanks, btw I managed to get it working doing pluck('value', 'key') in that exact order, ('key', 'value') order does not work for some reason

Comment: did you get all values you wanted in reverser order ?

Comment: @maxit go ahead and accept `oseintow` answer..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it, the reason for not getting all the values is that you interchanged your key value pair in the pluck function. And also bear in mind that array keys must be unique so php will do some truncation there.

Try this.

```
Setting::where('section', $section)->select('value', 'key')->pluck('value','key')->toArray();
```

Its seem weird but the value must come first the key after

Answer (score 0):

You are just Plucking the Value! That's why it is returning an array containing the values only!
Yes, Now you'll get Array of Arrays containing your Information.
To Solve that, Create an Empty Array and run `foreach` loop Just like this.

```
$processed_array = array();

foreach($entries as $entry){
    $processed_arrray[$entry->key] = $entry->value;
}
```

I think it's the best way to do it. You can create new function in your `Model.php` and whenever you want the Data in `key -> value` format in single array, You can just run `Model::yourCustomFunction($parameters);`. 
Hope this helps! Let me know if it's your solution.